# I am trying to make a post request using javascript to my fast api app. But it is giving error INFO. 422 Unprocessable Entity

Tags: javascript, post, xmlhttprequest

```
// variables for getting Original URL
const form2 = document.getElementById("form2");
const resultContainer2 = document.querySelector(".result__container2");
const longUrl = document.querySelector(".longurl");

//for decoding the url (Retrieving Original URL)
form2.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("shortUrl", e.target.shortUrl.value);
    formData.append("customCode", e.target.shortUrl.value);
    let data = {}
    for(let pair of formData.entries()) {
        data[pair[0]] = pair[1]
    }

    console.log(data)

    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "/api/v2/original", true);

    // Set the request header
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status === 200) {
            console.log("Done")
        }
    }

    //Displaying the Original long URL
    xhr.onload = function () {
        const response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        console.log(this.status);
        console.log(response);
        if(this.status ==200) {
            resultContainer2.style.display = "flex";
            longUrl.innerHTML = `ORIGINAL LONG URL :- <a href=${response.longUrl}>${response.longUrl}</a>`
        }
        else {
            alert(`An error occurred, ${response.detail}`)
        }
    };

    //using JSON for transfering data in between, as per task requirement (JSON Object to JSON string)
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
})
```

Comment: HTTP 422 can easily be returned because the request is missing required fields, even though the request is structured/formatted correctly.  Since this response is determined by logic on the server the question needs to see the server side code, or at least the documentation plus the data you're sending.  As it is, this question lacks debugging details.  Please make it a [mcve]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.